# How can I return different value based on the selected results?

Tags: sql

I have a very simple query like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM Users WHERE Age < 20;
```

I want to implement such a feature:

- If the result contains no value, return an empty string ''.
- If the result contains only 1 value, return the value.
- If the result contains more than 1 value, return a constant string 'Multiple'.

How can I implement this with a very simple query? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) in `SELECT` section to modify your `returned result`

Answer (score 0):

The following query can help you out with the 3 conditions.
Instead of an empty string i put in 'None' for sake of clarity. You may edit it to be an empty string..

```
select case when count(*)=0 then 'None'
            when count(name)=1 then max(name)
            when count(name)>1 then max('Multiple')
       end as name     
  from users1 
 where age <20
```

See a full demo with all the 3 test cases being catered to

1. No records with age <20
2. Exactly one record with age < 20
3. More than one record with age <20

Demo
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=929d6ffca27ab5c4c05eeabdb6dd8b12

Comment: Thanks a lot. Two more questions: 1. Why you use MAX here? Is it necessary? 2. If we call COUNT multiple times, will it be a performance issue?

Comment: 1. Any aggregated function that accepts <string_input> would do  MIN is also fine. It is necessary to have that as we are grouping by the result set of (WHERE age<20) to get count(*)/count(name). 2. The easiest way to count records would be to make use of the COUNT keyword. Also sql is a declarative language, so we cannot assume that count(*) would be called multiple times here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what "one value" refers to.  Does that mean one row?  Or one name (which could be on multiple rows)?

I would be inclined to phrase this as:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'None'
             WHEN MIN(Name) = MAX(Name) THEN MIN(Name)
             ELSE 'Multiple'
        END) as one_row_value
FROM Users
WHERE Age < 20;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, “one value” here means only one row is selected. I think both you and George are correct.